# How to change file access permissions in linux?

Tags: python

How does one change file access permissions?

```
f = open('test','w')
f.close()
```

Defaults access permissions: 10600

Answer (score 20):

You can use [os.chmod](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chmod)

```
os.chmod(path, mode)
```

You probably want to use an octal integer literal, like 0777 for the mode.

Comment: Please note that from [python2.6 onwards](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/) you need 0o777

Answer (score 5):

Use [os.chmod(path, mode)](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chmod)